# DeprecationWarning: Non-string object detected for the array ordering. Please pass in 'C', 'F', 'A', or 'K' instead

Tags: python, 3d

```
from stl import mesh
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib import pyplot

# Create a new plot
figure = pyplot.figure()
axes = mplot3d.Axes3D(figure)

# Load the STL files and add the vectors to the plot
your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file("/home/niroz/stl files/bottle/binary.stl")

axes.add_collection3d(mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(your_mesh.vectors))

# Auto scale to the mesh size
scale = your_mesh.points.flatten(-1)
axes.auto_scale_xyz(scale, scale, scale)

# Show the plot to the screen
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code is assuming an older version of `numpy`.

Newer versions of `numpy` (mine is 1.14.0) you can check the docstring in IPython by typing

```
np.ndarray.flatten?
```

and what I'm getting is:

```
Docstring:
a.flatten(order='C')

Return a copy of the array collapsed into one dimension.

Parameters
----------
order : {'C', 'F', 'A', 'K'}, optional
    'C' means to flatten in row-major (C-style) order.
    'F' means to flatten in column-major (Fortran-
    style) order. 'A' means to flatten in column-major
    order if `a` is Fortran *contiguous* in memory,
    row-major order otherwise. 'K' means to flatten
    `a` in the order the elements occur in memory.
    The default is 'C'.
```

The equivalent of passing `-1` is the `'F'` option, i.e. the following snippet:

```
import numpy as np

foo = np.array([[1,2,3], [3,4,5]])
print (foo.flatten(-1) == foo.flatten('F')).all()
```

produces `True` (and the `DeprecationWarning` you're asking about).